# psycopg2: export csv to database, dealing with e+ expression

Tags: pandas, psycopg2

I have a csv file containing

numbers like "1.456e+07"

and I am using function "copy_expert" to export the file to database

but I am getting error

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "1.5637e+07"
```

I notice that I can insert "100" as an integer, but when I do "1.5637e+07" with qoute, it doesn't work.

I am using pandas dataframe's to_csv to generate the csv files. not sure how to get rid of qoute for integer like "1.5637e+07" only (I have string column), or whether there is other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution

Normally, pandas doesn't put quotes around number. However, I set float_format parameter which causes this. I reset

```
quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
```

in the function call and the quotes go away.